# Creating a callback in C# to read lines from a text file

Tags: c#, callback

I have a parameter called `FileName` in my program.  It has no default value.  Whenever a value is set I would like a callback to trigger the reading of the file.  I am very new to `C#` so I have no idea how to create the callback.

The field is initialised as

```
public string FileName { get; set; }
```

And whenever its value is set I want to execute the following lines of code

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@FileName);
```

The setting of the variable `FileName` is done by the user and is handled nicely by the framework I'm using, so its just getting the callback that I need to understand.  As I understand it at the moment, because I'm not giving a default value for `FileName` it is by default `Null`

Comment: Why don't you provide a method `SetFile(string fileName)` which sets the `FileName` property(which is get-only then) and reads the file afterwards? I would prefer a method because otherwise it's not obvious from the`FileName` property that it triggers such an expensive operation.

Comment: What about adding this code to your setter in your FileName property ?

Comment: Generally, do not implement such expensive side effects to property setters/getters. Use a method for that whose name correctly and clearly reflects the behavior/purpose of the method, so instead of the property _FileName_, declare a method named something like _LoadFancyTextFile(string filePath)_ or something. Because `myInstance.FileName = @"x:\foo\bar.txt";` will naturally be read as assigning a (file path) string to a property, not as reading the file x:\foo\bar.txt. But then again, if you like to write code that looks weird, confusing, and easy to misunderstand, nobody's stopping you ;-)

Comment: ^^ What @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace said **plus**: I would be _**very**_ surprised if I did `myInstance.FileName = @"x:\foo\.bar.txt";` and it threw an Exception. Not because I wouldn't expect setters in general to throw but because I wouldn't expect a - what would look to me like - a simple string property specifically to throw.

Comment: Also mind: if you update the lines from one thread while another thread is still using the "old" ones: ka-boom. So, you may even think about making whatever class this is in immutable and instead of updating, create a new instance?

Comment: Thank you all for the comments.  As I said I'm quite new to C#.  Would it be possible to illustrate with some code examples?  For example (following the first comment) I can do the following 
```
public string[] SetFile(string FileName)
    {
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@FileName);
        return lines;
    }
```
But I have no idea how to trigger this when `FileName` is set, nor how to make it part of the setter

Comment: "_But I have no idea how to trigger this when FileName is set, nor how to make it part of the setter_" Did you not read any of the comments? (o.O)???

Comment: I read the comments.  I don't understand the difference between making the method (comment 1 and comment 3, your comment) part of the setter (comment 2), nor do I understand whether comment 2 is contradictory to your statement about implementing side effects to setters/getters.  I simply don't understand how that method is called, though perhaps that is a question for the framework.

Comment: "_I simply don't understand how that method is called, though perhaps that is a question for the framework._" You simply call that method **instead** of setting a property. I have no idea why you think you need a property. Ignore the 2nd comment, the commenter didn't think it through (no blame, happens to each of us sometimes...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have stated, it's unclear why you're adamant about setting a value to trigger the reading of a file. The following shows how one can get data from one Form (or class) to another Form (or class).

[image]

For more information, see:

- [Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors)
- [Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods)
- [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)

While all three can be used to pass data, the appropriateness of which one to use depends upon what one desires to occur.

**Constructor:**

Version 1 (Property):

```
public class Class1
{
    public string Filename { get; private set; }

    public Class1 (string filename)
    {
        Filename = filename;
    }
}
```

Version 2 (Field):

```
public class Class1
{
    private string _filename;

    public Class1 (string filename)
    {
        _filename = filename;
    }
}
```

---

**Method**:

Version 1 (Property)

```
public class Class1
{
    public string Filename { get; private set; }

    public void SetFilename (string filename)
    {
        Filename = filename;
    }
}
```

Version 2 (Field)

```
public class Class1
{
    private string _filename;

    public void SetFilename (string filename)
    {
        _filename = filename;
    }
}
```

---

**Property**:

Version 1:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string Filename { get; set; }
}
```

Version 2:

```
public class Class1
{
    private string _filename;

    public string Filename 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _filename;
        }
        set
        {
            _filename = value;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Your OP, seems to indicate that you are attempting to do something similar to the following:

**WARNING - The following is not recommended**:

```
public class Class1
{
    private string _filename;
    private string[] _lines = null;

    public string Filename 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _filename;
        }
        set
        {
            _filename = value;
             
            //read file
            _lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@FileName);
        }
    }
}
```

Depending upon the size of the file, this operation may take some time to complete. Therefore, it's not recommended to place code to read a file within a property setter.

**Instead use a method (recommended):**

Version 1:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string Filename { get; private set; }

    public string[] ReadFile (string filename)
    {
        //set value
        Filename = filename;

       //read file
       return System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename);
    }
}
```

Version 2:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string Filename { get; private set; }
    public string[] Lines { get; private set; } = null;

    public bool ReadFile(string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            //set value
            Filename = filename;

            //read file
            Lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //ToDo: add desired code
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Version 3:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string Filename { get; private set; }
    public string[] Lines { get; private set; } = null;

    public void ReadFile (string filename)
    {
        //set value
        Filename = filename;

       //read file
       Lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename);
    }
}
```

**Resources:**

- [Introduction to classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/classes)
- [Constructors (C# programming guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors)
- [Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods)
- [Properties (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)

Comment: The framework I am using does not allow end users to directly interact with methods of objects.  Rather then interact (before run-time, that is, which is when I need this procedure to take place) by setting parameters.  Thank you for this extrememly in depth and educational answer!  It is super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this? You just change the default setter and getter.

```
private string fileName;

public string FileName 
{ 
   get
   { 
      return fileName; 
   } 
   set 
   { 
      fileName = value; 
      string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@FileName);
   }
}
```

But maybe this is a bad idea, read the comments :-)

Comment: "_I think you want this?_" Someone wants to dig themselves a hole, hand them a spade!